# proving Uniqueness in fundamental theorem of symmetric functions

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to prove that if a symmetric polynomial can be written as

$\sum b_i* \sigma_1\cdot\ldots \cdot\sigma_n = \sum c_i* \sigma_1\cdot\ldots \cdot\sigma_n$

where the $\sigma_i$s are the symmetric elementary polynomials.

then $b_i = c_i$ for all index. My manual says that it is sufficient to prove that if $\phi(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n) = 0$ then all coefficients of $\phi(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ are zero, i.e. the polynomials in the indeterminates $z_i$, $\phi(z_1,\ldots,z_n) = 0$.

the manual says that I've to prove that the $\sigma_i$ are *algebrically independent* by showing that

$\phi(z_1,...,z_n) ≠ 0   ⇒   \phi(σ_1,...,σ_n) ≠ 0$

but if one sigma can be expressed in terms of a not null combination, wouldn't this mean that I can express a monomial in terms of others, and hence have two formal writings for the same polynomial?

look here also

[image]

Comment: What does $b_i\ast \sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n$ mean?

Comment: Guess: the $\sigma_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials and it should be $\sum b_i \sigma_i = \sum c_i \sigma_i$.

Comment: But even that would just establish linear independence (which follows from them being different degrees and having no terms in common!) not algebraic independence.